# how to run the mapreduce matrix multiplication example

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I am in learning process of mapreduce and haddoop. I want to run the example of matrix multiplitaction presented here along with its code:

http://www.norstad.org/matrix-multiply/index.html

I know its a strange question but Can someone please guide me that how can I run this example as I could not find any guidance for this particular example. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have hadoop configured in pseudodistributed mode.

regards,

WL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code is self explanatory for running the program.

1. First the source has to be compiled and jar'd.
2. Both the input matrix should be in the SequenceFile format. TestMultiplyMatrix#writeMatrix has the sample for creating a random matrix.
3. Put the input matrix sequence files into HDFS.

Here are the input parameters to run the job. The details of each of the parameter is on top of the MatrixMultiply#runJob method.

> bin/hadoop jar jar_file_name MatrixMultiply [generic args] inputPathA inputPathB outputDirPath tempDirPath strategy R1 R2 I K J IB KB JB

Comment: thanks praveen for your help but can you please guide me that how can I create sequence files from the testmultiplymatrix.

Comment: infact it tried and while running the program it gives the message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/io/writable at.......bla bla